# What version do I download for my Mac?

Tags: installation, downloads

I am trying to get it on my mac, so do I download the windows version onto a USB and then upload it from there because I can't find a mac version.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the version of Ubuntu you download does matter, though there are not specific builds for Mac hardware vs. PC hardware.  Not all the versions are compatible with all the models of MacBook.  Fortunately, there is [an awesome guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro) that breaks it down by model and tells you which versions will work.

This guide will also give you great instructions about improving compatibility with Mac hardware.

If you have an Intel based Mac, you may want to install the [Mactel Support Team PPA](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MactelSupportTeam/PPA).  Follow [the instructions for your specific model](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro) and you'll do fine.

Answer (score 1):

There are no differences for Mac or PC as far as the downloaded installer file goes. There are different directions for creating a bootable USB stick or DVD for each platform, so if you are using this on a Mac, follow the directions for either the [USB stick](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) or [DVD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-mac-osx). And you can always try Ubunutu before installing by following the directions [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install).

Comment: well, there is wubi...

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen Wubi is for Windows and has been deprecated on 13.04.

Comment: O... Good, it was pointless anyway. I forgot about 13.04 tbh.

Answer (score 1):

Since Ubuntu is a separate operating system, you do not have to download a specific version for the operating system you are using prior to Ubuntu.

You just need to install a version that works on your hardware.  In most cases on recent hardware, this will be the 64-bit desktop version.